# WinZip command line sync vs async

Tags: powershell, command-line, synchronization, winzip

I am using WinZip 25 enterprise to zip a folder using AES 256 bit encryption.
The command used is

```
$PathToWinZipExe = "C:\Program Files\WinZip\WZZIP.EXE"
$ZipPassword = "somethingLongToFitCriteria"
$sourceDir ="C:\MyFolder"
$sourceDir ="C:\MyFolder.zip"
$zipResult = & $PathToWinZipExe -ybc -a -r -p -en -s"$ZipPassword" -ycAES256 $destFileNameFullPath $sourceDir
```

Can anyone help me with above command to make zip creation synchronously. Based on [this](https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2006/cc/CC01.pdf) document it looks like the default behavior is async.

Comment: Are you running SAS on Windows?

Comment: @lit Yes, on windows.

Comment: Are you using the %WZZIP SAS macro? That is apparently where XSYNC is specified.

Comment: I'm confused, why is this Powershell but you're talking about SAS? Are you using SAS?  Or Powershell?

Comment: I removed the SAS tag